# Why TomCat 8 can't work on my Ubuntu 15.04 system?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I have installed **TomCat 8** on an **Ubuntu 15.04** system using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat8 tomcat8-docs tomcat8-admin tomcat8-examples
```

So I have that the installation directory is:

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/bin
```

So I enter in this directory and I perform this command to start the server:

```
sudo ./startup.sh
```

And I obtain this:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin$ sudo ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

So I think that the server is started.

The problem is that if I try to open this URL **http://localhost:8080/** into a browser I obtain the error message **Connection failed** (I don't know it it is the right translation in English language because I see it in Italian language).

If I try to open this URL ****http://localhost** (without the **8080** port specification) I obtain the **Apache 2** web server information page (I used it for some PHP website).

If I try to perform the **TomCat** shutdown I obtain this error message:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin$ sudo ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
lug 16, 2015 2:13:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
GRAVE: Catalina.stop: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml (File o directory non esistente)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)
```

So what could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Tnx

Comment: You are missing following file: /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml  Check if it is there and if your tomcat process has right permission to read it

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml` Do you have this file in above path ?

Comment: Is it not automatically created when the application is installed? What content have I to put inside this file?

Comment: It suppose to be there. Check if it is there.

Comment: @user987339 I find it into another path, this one: /etc/tomcat8

Answer (score 1):

When you install Tomcat in Ubuntu using apt, it is installed as a service. To start and stop it, you should use the following commands:

```
sudo service tomcat8 start
sudo service tomcat8 stop
```

You can also use this command to see its current status:

```
sudo service tomcat8 status
```

Before trying this you may want to reboot just to make sure you don't have any other Tomcat process running in the background.